# Можно ли преобразовать кадр с вебкамеры opencv в JPEG не сохраняя его на диске

Tags: c++, opencv

Есть задача, преобразовать получаемые с вебки кадры в jpeg и отправлять их в браузер. Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли преобразовать кадр, из формата iplImage в jpeg, не тратя ресурсы на сохраняние на диск? Если нельзя, то как это обмен лучше реализовать, вот что есть

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY); //cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
    assert( capture );

    IplImage* frame= nullptr;

    cvNamedWindow("capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


    while (true)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/378.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33538510/8099156